# Desktop App Development with AIR-like (Flash) UI Creation

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash, air

*I love to code app, and I love to design/draw app UI.*

I previously have developed a desktop application (just a simple one) in AIR with Flash Professional as the IDE. I love it, it's so easy. I just need to drag and drop, overlay some components over the others, and relate each other with codes written in ActionScript3. It's so easy to make an application with beautiful UI (chromeless, image-based UI components).

But now since I didn't see any new thing from AIR (especially about the availability in Windows 8), I decided to change to a new development platform (or so what it's called).

But I couldn't find any platform that could help me develop an application with an UI as easy as AIR. I've tried C# with MonoDevelop aka Xamarin, with Unity (it's so funny I tried to make a desktop app with it :D), and browsed (only browsed) about WPF, WinForm, TideSDK, Cappuccino and I found it's so hard to create a good UI like in AIR. And no one has Flash-like workflow.

What I'm trying to ask is what should I use (dev language or framework) so I could apply UI component I drawn (like in Photoshop or else) as a real desktop app? And that supports chromeless window.

I don't mind learning new devlpmnt language. Or maybe I missed some important point at those that I've tried? Help me, i've been so unproductive lately.. (so sorry it's so long)

Comment: @HighCore: No, I'm not talking flash as a desktop programming platform actually. But AIR. And I used Flash (Flash Professional) as the IDE. Flash I mentioned up there is not Flash that installed on browser or what it is called. But what I meant is Flash Professional, the application. It's hard since both have a same name really.

Comment: my point still stands. If you need to create serious software, use serious platforms (C# + XAML + .Net + WPF / WinRT).

Comment: @HighCore. You are mistaken. Flash 11.4+ supports concurrency (http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2012/08/flash-player-11-4-and-air-3-4.html).

Comment: @DavidArno yeah, I'm pretty sure some fancy Flash stuff will replace the power of HTML5 + any of the JavaScript frameworks out there today for the Web, or the power of C# + XAML for Windows Applications. Look dude, I'm not allowed to talk about how much technologies suck here anymore, otherwise I'll get banned. If you want to do some discussion, create a chat room in SO chat and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Node-Webkit](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/introduction-to-html5-desktop-apps-with-node-webkit/) is what you are after? It lets you use HTML5 + JS to create desktop apps. Seems a natural progression from Flash/AIR.